# Vectorize the following python code?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

I am trying to vectorize the following operations with two matrix in python.

```
f= matrix([[ 96],
    [192],
    [288],
    [384]], dtype=int32)

g = matrix([[   0.],
    [  70.],
    [ 200.],
    [  60.]])
```

Need to create z without creating loops such that z is maximum of cumulative sum of first column and sum of last value of z and another matrix g. This loop is called thousands of time, therefore slowing the  run time.

```
for i in range(4):
if i != 0:
    z[i] = max(f[i], z[i-1] + g[i])
else:
    z[0] = f[i]
```

Any guidance on how to vectorize this code would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given the type of dependency, would be hard, if not impossible.

Comment: Use `numpy.array`, not `numpy.matrix` (deprecated).

Comment: sure. could use numpy.array as well. Any idea to speed up the run time of the code

Comment: Since `z[i]` depends on `z[i-1]`, you can't really "vectorize"
 this.

Comment: To gain perf : Initialize `z[0]` to `f[0]` and get rid of the else part and start `i` with `1`.

Comment: Any improvement would I get using apply function on array

Comment: Have you tried `numba`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately numba is giving higher time per loop

Comment: Think you might be using numba wrongly. Are you using `@njit` with it?

Comment: nope. Just tried it. the results were very fast compared to other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized version. It uses the cumulative `maximum` on the difference between `f` and `cumsum(g)` to predict the points where `f[i]` is larger than `z[i]`:

Timings:

```
N = 10
loopy                 0.00594156 ms
vect                  0.03193051 ms
N = 100
loopy                 0.05560229 ms
vect                  0.03186400 ms
N = 1000
loopy                 0.57484017 ms
vect                  0.04492043 ms
N = 10000
loopy                 5.75115310 ms
vect                  0.15519847 ms
N = 100000
loopy                57.30253551 ms
vect                  1.69428380 ms
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np

import types
from timeit import timeit

def setup_data(N):
    g = np.random.random((N,))
    f = 2 + np.cumsum(np.random.random(N,))
    return f, g

def f_loopy(f, g):
    N, = f.shape
    z = np.empty_like(f)
    for i in range(N):
        if i != 0:
            z[i] = max(f[i], z[i-1] + g[i])
        else:
            z[0] = f[i]
    return z

def f_vect(f, g):
    N, = f.shape
    gg = np.cumsum(g)
    rmx = np.maximum.accumulate(f - gg)
    sw = np.r_[0, 1 + np.flatnonzero(rmx[:-1] != rmx[1:]), N]
    return gg + np.repeat(f[sw[:-1]]-gg[sw[:-1]], np.diff(sw))

for N in [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]:
    data = setup_data(N)
    ref = f_loopy(*data)
    print(f'N = {N}')
    for name, func in list(globals().items()):
        if not name.startswith('f_') or not isinstance(func, types.FunctionType):
            continue
        try:
            assert np.allclose(ref, func(*data))
            print("{:16s}{:16.8f} ms".format(name[2:], timeit(
                'f(*data)', globals={'f':func, 'data':data}, number=100)*10))
        except:
            print("{:16s} apparently failed".format(name[2:]))
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me take a look and compare values

Comment: Works well. Thanks Paul for your help